# MouseEvent's click with CtrlKey not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick question; I want to open a link in a new tab without focusing on it (just like Ctrl+Click in Firefox), However the `ctrlKey: true` doesn't seem to be working.

Here's a sample code:

HTML :

```
<a href="something.com" id="link">Sample link</a>
```

Javascript :

```
var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: 20,
    ctrlKey: true,
    }, ele = document.getElementById("link"));
ele.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/932wyok6/51/)

Comment: In Chromium, this is forbidden by pop-under prevention, see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487919 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=431335

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this from the other side:

```
$("#link").attr("target","_blank")[0].click();
```

Comment: "I want to open a link in a new tab without focusing on it", I want to stay on the same page while opening a link in a new tab, That's why i wanted to use ctrlKey;

Comment: That's a browser specific feature, so there is a good chance it won't work everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. Did you ever get an answer?
I find the ctrlKey is part working; it correctly makes it open in a new tab, but does not correctly keep focus on the original page.